# Angular Testing - Tick doesn't work if timer is in component initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, timer

### Question

How do I get `tick` to work, or at least, how do I get the test to advance 10s to appropriately call `submit` in my component?

Note: I don't want to do `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000))` because it will make my tests run long, and tests are supposed to be short

### Goal

I want `submit` to only call `cb` after 10 seconds has elapsed from the creation of the component

### Description

I have a timer in my component that completes after 10s. This timer changes a subject from false to true, and is used to determine whether or not it is considered *valid* to submit the data in the component.

In testing, `tick` does not seem to advance the timer at all, and it actually runs a full 10s. I attempted to fix this by putting a `fakeAsync` in the `beforeEach` that creates the component to no avail.

### What I have tried

- Using `fakeAsync` in the test component init, as well as the test
- Using `fakeAsync` in only the test
- Using `setTimeout(() => this.obs.next(true), 10_000)` instead of timer
- Using `empty().pipe(delay(10000)).subscribe(() => this.obs.next(true));` instead of timer
- Putting the `timer` in `ngOnInit` instead of constructor
- Putting the `timer` in constructor instead of `ngOnInit`

### Observations

If you adjust this code

```js
    timer(10_000).subscribe(() => this.testThis$.next(true));
```

to instead be this

```js
    timer(10_000).subscribe(() => {
      debugger;
      this.testThis$.next(true)
    });
```

You will find that every time a test runs, the Javascript debugger in Dev Tools is triggered 10 seconds after component creation (instead of instantly if tick worked).

### Code

Here's the code. At the bottom is a link to a minimal reproduction on GitHub.

```js
// component code
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { first, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tick-test',
  templateUrl: './tick-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tick-test.component.scss']
})
export class TickTestComponent implements OnInit {

  public testThis$: Subject<boolean>;

  constructor(
    @Inject('TICK_CALLBACK') private readonly cb: () => void,
  ) {
    this.testThis$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    timer(10_000).subscribe(() => this.testThis$.next(true));
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public submit(): void {
    // call the callback after 10s
    this.testThis$
      .pipe(first(), filter(a => !!a))
      .subscribe(() => this.cb());
  }

}
```

```js
// test code
/**
 * The problem in this one is that I am expecting `tick` to advance the
 * time for the timer that was created in the constructor, but it is not working
 */



import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TickTestComponent } from './tick-test.component';

describe('TickTestComponent', () => {
  let component: TickTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TickTestComponent>;

  let callback: jasmine.Spy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    callback = jasmine.createSpy('TICK_CALLBACK');

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: 'TICK_CALLBACK', useValue: callback },
      ],
      declarations: [ TickTestComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TickTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be true after 10s', fakeAsync(() => {
    tick(10_001);

    component.submit();
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

### Minimal Reproduction Repo

[Link To Github](https://github.com/jschmold/ng-broken-tick)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

1. Move `fixture.detectChanges()` into each test, and call `tick(10_000)` there.
2. Move `timer(10_000)...` to the `ngOnInit` in the component

### What was happening

Whenever you use `fakeAsync` a "zone" that your code can run in is made. From my observations, this zone "exists" until it goes out of scope. By using `fakeAsync` in the `beforeEach`, you destroy the zone and you get issues with the timer not finishing (despite the timer not finishing being the desireable outcome).

You want to move the `timer` into the `ngOnInit` because it is NOT called immediately upon the `.createComponent` call. It is *instead* called when you run `fixture.detectChanges()` for the first time. Thus when you call `fixture.detectChanges()` inside of a test's `fakeAsync` zone for the first time, `ngOnInit` is called for you, the timer is captured in the zone, and you can control time as expected.

### Code

```
describe('TickTestComponent', () => {
  let component: TickTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TickTestComponent>;

  let callback: jasmine.Spy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    callback = jasmine.createSpy('TICK_CALLBACK');

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: 'TICK_CALLBACK', useValue: callback },
      ],
      declarations: [ TickTestComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TickTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // don't run this here
    // fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be true after 10s', fakeAsync(() => {
    // this calls ngOnInit if it is the first detectChanges call
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick(10_001);

    component.submit();
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```